# Use live activity with a timer instead of push notification

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have already implemented method where I'am generating some push notifications between specific time interval. And I have implemented method where im handling notification such that if user opens notifications within 1 minute, it prints "Success' and if user does not open notification within 1 min, it will print "Failed".
Then I decided to use live activity instead of notifications as it seems more logical to show a timer directly showing countdown. I used very basic implementation and got it working using buttons where I can start or stop the live activity. However I want live activities to start as soon as notification comes. it would be even better if user just sees a live activity instead of the notification but with some sound. Here is what I have done so far:

```
let numberOfNotifications = 24

let intervalBetweenNotifications = timeRange / TimeInterval(numberOfNotifications)

            for i in 1...numberOfNotifications {
                let randomTimeInterval = TimeInterval.random(in: 0...intervalBetweenNotifications)
                let notificationDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(i) * intervalBetweenNotifications + randomTimeInterval)

                let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: notificationDate)
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

                let userInfo = ["notificationFiredAt": notificationDate]
                content.userInfo = userInfo

                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

                center.add(request) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error)
                    }
                }

                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState != .active {
                    center.add(request) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            debugPrint(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The above method shedules 24 notifications between any timeRange that I provide. It works fine. And I use below method to print success or failed based on when user taps on the notification:

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
            // User tapped on notification
            if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String: Any],
               let notificationFiredAt = userInfo["notificationFiredAt"] as? Date {
                let oneMinAgo = Date().addingTimeInterval(-60)
                if notificationFiredAt >= oneMinAgo {
                    // Notification was tapped within 1 min
                   print("sucess")
                } else {
                    // Notification wasnt tapped on time
                    print("failed")
                }
            } else {
                // Error: unable to extract notification fired date from userInfo
                print("failed")
            }
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Up until now everything is as I desire, user gets a notification. if he taps within 1 min, it prints "success" otherwise "failed".
Now I want same functionality but instead want to use Live Activities. This is my struct for Activity Attributes:

```
struct TimeActivityAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public typealias = TimerStatus = ContentState
    
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        // Dynamic stateful properties about your activity go here!
        var endTime: Date
    }

    // Fixed non-changing properties about your activity go here!
    var name: String
}
```

And this is how I tried to start activity:

```
    var activity: Activity<TimeActivityAttributes>? = nil
    
    func startActivity() {
        let attributes = TimeActivityAttributes(name: "Timer")
        let state = TimeActivityAttributes.TimerStatus(endTime: Date().addingTimeInterval(120))
        
        activity =  try? Activity<TimerActivityAttributes>.request(attributes: attributes, contentState:  state, pushType: .token)
    }
```

If I put `pushType: nil`, it works fine and activity starts but I read online I need to set its type as token so when I do, nothing happens. Also where should I call this method. I tried to call it inside `scheduleNotifications` method but it started live activity as soon as that method was called instead of starting when a notification is received.
Any idea how to implement this? I read official documentation and read some examples but all of them are in SwiftUI. Is it possible to schedule live activities just like those notifications too?